# PHP Reflection Class. How to get the values of the properties?

Tags: php, reflection, get

I'm using the reflection class in PHP, but I'm with no clues on how to get the values of the properties in the reflection instance. It is possible?

The code:

```
<?php

class teste {

    public $name;
    public $age;

}

$t = new teste();
$t->name = 'John';
$t->age = '23';

$api = new ReflectionClass($t);

foreach($api->getProperties() as $propertie)
{
    print $propertie->getName() . "\n";
}

?>
```

How can I get the propertie values inside the foreach loop?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about

- [`ReflectionProperty::getValue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getvalue.php) - Gets the properties value.

In your case:

```
foreach ($api->getProperties() as $propertie)
{
    print $propertie->getName() . "\n";
    print $propertie->getValue($t);
}
```

On a sidenote, since your object has only public members, you could just as well [iterate it directly](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)

```
foreach ($t as $propertie => $value)
{
    print $propertie . "\n";
    print $value;
}
```

or fetch them with [`get_object_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) into an array.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to use the [getDefaultProperties()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdefaultproperties.php) method, if you don't want to instantiate that class, eg.

```
$api->getDefaultProperties();
```

Here's your full example reduced to what you're looking for...

```
class teste {

    public $name;
    public $age;

}

$api = new ReflectionClass('teste');
var_dump($api->getDefaultProperties());
```

Note: you can also use namespaces inside of that ReflectionClass. eg,

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('Some\Namespaced\Class');
var_dump($class->getDefaultProperties());
```