# Looping Class Property

Tags: php, oop

how to looping all property of Class

```
class object {
    public $a = 1;
    public $b = 2;
    public $c = 3;
}
```

and the output will be

```
"property $a is 1";
"property $b is 2";
"property $c is 3";
```

Comment: What are you trying to **do**? What's the goal of this? An array may suit your problem much better than any reflection-based solution.

Comment: my goal is to set the result property of `mysql_fetch_object()` into PHP object

Comment: @GusDe CooL: Can't you just pass the class name `"object"` to that function and it'll return your results as those objects automatically?

Comment: Even if you do this through a reflection-style operation such as BoltClock's answer, you'll still need to validate the value of each parameter before using it anywhere. There are very few cases where you can skip validation.

Comment: Look for `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` in http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php - this *might* be what you're looking for - or make use of the `$class_name` parameter in [`mysql_fetch_object`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_object) to encapsulate your logic into the returned object itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Reflection Class. How to get the values of the properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995321/php-reflection-class-how-to-get-the-values-of-the-properties) - shows two variants: Reflection and for-each.

Comment: @Polynomial: yes it is, im going need to do some validation like if the value type is NULL, Integer and Double or Float.

Comment: @hakre: i think i will not use PDO at the moment, since i use PHP 5.2

Comment: @GusDeCooL: Similar is possible with `mysql_fetch_object` as well, I added it to the previous comment. Might be helpful, you can make the object validate itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [use a foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php):

```
foreach (new object as $prop => $value) {
    echo "property \$$prop is $value\n";
}
```

Comment: wow i didn't know if `foreach()` can be used for object to. Will try and test it :D

Comment: This "only" works if the object has the default `Iterator` behaviour. Just noting.

Comment: i unclear about you mean `Iterator`, do you has a link explain about that?

Comment: @GusDe The starting point is http://docs.php.net/control-structures.foreach , from there follow the link in "As of PHP 5, it is possible to customize objects iteration too."

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php), but not after taking a look at Polynomial's comment.

Comment: yes, i avoiding use `ger_object_vars()`, since i need do some change value Type.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by that.