# Get the property value through Reflection in PHP

Tags: php

I have a class in PHP

```
class Test
{

private $name;

public setName($name)
{
$this->name = $name;
}

public getName()
{
return this->name;
}

}
```

I want to get the value of name property using Reflection.

How to achieve this in **PHP** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Reflection Class. How to get the values of the properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995321/php-reflection-class-how-to-get-the-values-of-the-properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as searching: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reflectionclass.getproperty.php, take a look at PHP documentation and examples.

And after getting a ReflectionProperty instance, just do `getValue`
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reflectionproperty.getvalue.php

```
$test = new Test();
$test->setName('hello, world');

$reflection = new ReflectionClass($test);
$property = $reflection->getProperty('name');
$property->setAccessible(true);
var_dump($property->getValue($test));
```